# How do I call a method from a class with 2 objects?

Tags: c#, class, object, fractions

My task is to add 2 fractions.

```
Fraction 1 = new Fraction(1,3);
Fraction 2 = new Fraction(2,4);
```

I already made the method in the class to add them.

The problem is how do i call that method ?
Like this ?

```
Fraction 3 = new Fraction(0);
3.add(1,2);
```

but that doens't work ive no idea tbh.

Comment: do you have the add method in the Fraction class?

Comment: yes in the fraction class

but i want to call it in the main.
my teacher said im only allowed to use only 1 parameter but how

Comment: Do you understand how `this` works in an instance method?  Remember, `this` is a parameter!

Comment: Also, your sample code is confusing because you are using numbers as variable names. Variable names may not start with a number in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are allowed to use only 1 parameter, you can do it like this:

```
class Fraction
{
int integerPart;
int floatPart;
public void add(Fraction fraction)
{
this.integerPart += fraction.integerPart;
this.floatPart += fraction.floatPart;
}
}
```

and then in main use:

```
Fraction obj1 = new Fraction(1,2);
Fraction obj2 = new Fraction(2,3);
obj1.add(obj2);
```

This is a basic example, I have not put in validations etc. But you get the point I assume.

Comment: but what are you doing here ?

public void add(Fraction fraction)
{
this.integerPart += fraction.integerPart;
this.floatPart += fraction.floatPart;
}

this not the add right ?  i dont get it

Comment: You can either pass the integer part and float part as different parameters, or pass an object, which part of it you don't get?

Comment: not really :c 
so that means you save with this. the values from the obj1 in the properties integerPart and floatPart which are the denominator and numerator. why is your parameter fraction fraction ? why did you  make a new object 
classes are so confusing

Comment: +1 Good answer. Val, when you are learning it, sometimes just doing it can help. You can easily get stuck if you impose it upon yourself to completely understand a concept before trying it. Just follow Saransh's example. When you create the class object, you have access to the add method. So, you can use either objects add method: obj1.add(obj2) or obj2.add(obj1).